# R Shiny object not found within reactive if statement

Tags: r, shiny

I have a R shiny app that generate various reports. Now I would like to add the option to exclude some part of the data that is used to generate some graphs with checkbox input.

Here is a reproductible example :

App.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("exclude_x", "Exclude x", FALSE),
    plotOutput("plot")

)


server <- function(input, output) {

    source('data.R', local = TRUE)


    output$plot<-renderPlot({
        g<-ggplot(data=data(),aes(x=salary)) + geom_bar()
        g
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

data.R

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(10200, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))


employ_data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


data <- reactive({

    data <-      employ_data %>% 

        mutate(x_1 = 2*salary) %>% 
        { if (input$exclude_x == TRUE)
            filter( x_1 < 35000 )
            else .
        }   

})
```

It works fine when the box is unticked (plots the whole thing), but when I tick the box, I get the following error :

Warning: Error in filter: object 'x_1' not found

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your server code as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  #source('data.R', local = TRUE)


  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    g<-ggplot(data=data(),aes(x=salary)) + geom_bar()
    g
  })

  data <- reactive({

    data <-      employ_data %>% 
      mutate(x_1 = 2*salary)

    if (input$exclude_x == TRUE)
      filter(data, x_1 < 35000 )

  })
}
```

I think your filter(x1 < 35000) line was causing the error since your app was looking for an object called x_1. Changed to filter(data, x_1 < 35000) instead.